# Rebirth in regard to AI

Tags: philosophy, rebirth, modern-world

First time poster here. I am very new to buddhism, so my understanding is very basic. My previous world views were very materialistic and deterministic. It might not be surprising that the most confusing concept I find so far is rebirth.

Lets take this theoretical situation: We created AI that is indistinguishable from a human, capable of superior understanding of all the scientific concepts known to human and beyond.

- Will something have to be rebirth into it?
- Imagine this AI starts to multiplicate unstoppably, from where will we source all the consciousness to get rebirth into it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well to Buddhism SE. Interesting questions. However you will get a better response with a more focussed question. Would you consider splitting you question in two - one for each bullet point.

Comment: Crab, thank you for suggestion. I will do that.

Comment: Can an AI examine itself and make decisions to improve its "thinking" to align with Buddist ideals? YES, of course! Can an AI meditate and produce the same results that a human can? It can achieve some insight and improve its logic towards right thought and right action, but cannot achieve much else. Can an AI become enlightened? I am not qualified to answer that. Great thought provoker of a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AI no matter how sophisticated, is still just a sophisticated computer. It can even be 100% "human-like" but it's still not "human". See John Searle's [Chinese room experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room) for more details.

Comment: This is the exact argument I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

AI is a concept. Not a reality. AI in essence is simply electrified hardware. 
A computer is [Rupa](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mendis/wheel322.html#ruupa). Electricity is Rupa. There has to be [Nama](http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/n_r/naama.htm) involved to talk about rebirth or having a consciousness. A computer might beat a man in Chess. But it's still just matter. No mind involved.

Comment: I am talking about human like AI. AI will get to the point where it might be indistinguishable from a human, what then? Theoretically: imagine AI capable of creativity and understanding of a human.

Comment: A computer can be intelligent and smarter than a human. Isn't that how a computer beats you at chess? :)  One can also make a computer emulate human emotions. But it doesn't matter as long as there's no Nama.